# Why is `npx create-react-app` not doing anything?

Tags: reactjs

No errors, no messages just

```
$ npx create-react-app testapp
Please specify the project directory:
  create-react-app <project-directory>

For example:
  create-react-app my-react-app

Run create-react-app --help to see all options.
```

I am using nvm and nvm current = v20.5.1
I don't know how to track what the script is doing.

```
$ npx create-react-app --info

Environment Info:

  current version of create-react-app: 5.0.1
  running from /home/devuser/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.1/lib/node_modules/create-react-app

  System:
    OS: Linux 4.19 Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 10 (buster)
    CPU: (6) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 20.5.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.8.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.1/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 111.0.5563.64
  npmPackages:
    react: Not Found
    react-dom: Not Found
    react-scripts: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-app: 5.0.1
```

**Update**
Changed nvm to lts (18.17.1). Still no love from CRA.

???!!

** Update 2 2023-09-22 **
I created a new user in the system and that user was able to use it just fine.

The short answer is that something was screwed up in my shell environment.
Easier to scrap it and rebuild the environment.

Comment: Does it work if you add a directory to the end of the command? Fully qualified or relative. ie: `npx create-react-app testapp .`, `npx create-react-app testapp /users/Ken/home/...`

Comment: No it just spits back the helper text.

Comment: And did you check to see if that's a known issue over on https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues? That said, looks like they walked away from the project entirely, so if anything's broken, good chance it'll never get fixed anymore. Today's React apps of choice are Vite or Nextjs.

Comment: Oh. I see. Ok. I left an issue, but it sounds like that will never be seen.